# UPDATE: How to send Json Data as a POST request in Meteor using http package

Tags: javascript, json, rest, post, constantcontact

**UPDATE**: I have updated my code with the recommended answer, and am now getting a different error than I originally did, explained below.

I am using Meteor js [http package](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html) and I am attempting to send a POST request to the [Constant Contact API](https://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-collection.html?method=POST). I am trying to use the `data` option to pass in a JSON-able object to stringify and use as the HTTP request body. I am getting a 400 error response from Constant Contact. Using the [Constant Contact API tester](https://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-collection.html) I was able to successfully get a 201 response and Add a contact. The Json I have here is the same that I used in the tester but I get the following error back.

```
{ [Error: failed [400] [{"error_key":"query.param.invalid","error_message":"The query parameter status is not supported."},{"error_key":"query.param.invalid","error_message":"The query parameter limit is not supported."}]]
```

Here is my code below.

```
var data = {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "address_type": "BUSINESS",
          "city": "Belleville",
          "country_code": "CA",
          "line1": "47 Shawmut Ave.",
          "line2": "Suite 404",
          "postal_code": "K8b 5W6",
          "state_code": "ON"
        }
      ],
      "lists": [
        {
          "id": "1395617465"
        }
      ],
      "cell_phone": "555-555-5555",
      "company_name": "System Optimzations",
      "confirmed": false,
      "email_addresses": [
        {
          "email_address": "username2@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "fax": "555-555-5555",
      "first_name": "Ronald",
      "home_phone": "555-555-5555",
      "job_title": "Systems Analyst 3",
      "last_name": "Martone",
      "prefix_name": "Mr.",
      "work_phone": "555-555-5555"
    };

   HTTP.post('https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts?status=ALL&limit=50&api_key=<random-key>', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <random-token>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }, function (error, response) {
      if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
      } else {
        console.log(response);

      }
    });
```

Comment: headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }

Comment: @orangespark that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @AndersKitson Are you sure you updated your code based the recommended answer? I can still see your endpoint is incorrect. And so does the error reflects the same.

Comment: I changed my endpoint and I now gett this error `{ [Error: failed [400] [{"error_key":"json.type.invalid","error_message":"#/: Value is of a disallowed type. Allowed types are: Object."}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct url for POST is
`https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts?action_by=ACTION_BY_OWNER&api_key=<api-key>`

not

`https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts?status=ALL&limit=50&api_key=<random-key>`

Please see docs here: https://constantcontact.mashery.com/io-docs *Contact methods* section.

Comment: I still get the same 400 response error when I change the url.

Comment: @AndersKitson, If you get exactly the same error, you probably have not changed the url (or have changed it in the wrong place, or haven't saved the changes etc.). If the error text is different, please post it.

Comment: this is the new error I am getting `{ [Error: failed [400] [{"error_key":"json.type.invalid","error_message":"#/: Value is of a disallowed type. Allowed types are: Object."}]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "address_type": "BUSINESS",
          "city": "Belleville",
          "country_code": "CA",
          "line1": "47 Shawmut Ave.",
          "line2": "Suite 404",
          "postal_code": "K8b 5W6",
          "state_code": "ON"
        }
      ],
      "lists": [
        {
          "id": "1395617465"
        }
      ],
      "cell_phone": "555-555-5555",
      "company_name": "System Optimzations",
      "confirmed": false,
      "email_addresses": [
        {
          "email_address": "username2@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "fax": "555-555-5555",
      "first_name": "Ronald",
      "home_phone": "555-555-5555",
      "job_title": "Systems Analyst 3",
      "last_name": "Martone",
      "prefix_name": "Mr.",
      "work_phone": "555-555-5555"
    };
```

Now , convert object to JSON using `JSON.stringify` and add `Content-Type` header.

```
HTTP.post('https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts?action_by=ACTION_BY_OWNER&api_key=<api-key>',{
          headers:{
            'Authorization': 'Bearer <api-key>',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
        function (error, response) {
          if ( error ) {
            console.log( error );
          } else {

              console.log(response);

          }
        });
```

Comment: I am now getting a error `Unexpected token, expected ,` on the last line, something must be wrong.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code fixed for the error, now I am trying to figure out why the response from Constant Contact api is giving me a 400, I have updated my question and code above.